# Why doesn't useMutation return a promise?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, es6-promise, react-query, tanstackreact-query

My axios instance that just returns a promise:

`` export const add_order = (data) => instance.post(`/Order/addItem`, { ...data }); ``

My mutation:

`const { mutate } = useMutation(add_order);`

So my question now is:

- Why can't i use mutate to await results? Looks like useMutation just uses callbacks, doesn't actually return a promise...

Eaxmple:

```
  const myPostFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await mutate(itemsForOrder)
    console.log(result)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I just can't use await on mutate...
My VSC says can't use await on this kind of expression, and thats true, i dont get anything console logged, like result isn't awaited

Any insight?

Comment: use `mutateAsync`?

Answer (score 3):

There's an async version of mutate if you do want to wait on mutate: you can use

`const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(...)`

[Documentation here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations#promises)

Comment: Wow, how did i miss that.
Yes you're totally right, thanks!

Comment: Btw can mutateAsync have onSuccess and other callbacks?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can also provide those as a second argument